# DataStax Cassandra - Scala Spark Application - SBT Build failure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, datastax-enterprise

I have a simple demo Scala application that reads from a file and outputs to the screen. I am trying to build this application using sbt and submit it to DataStax Spark. The SBT instructions in the DataStax documentation seems to be incomplete. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html
Using this as-is did not work because of the lacking link to datastax repo.

After searching around for a bit, found a sample build.sbt file from https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/blob/master/scala/sbt/dse/build.sbt which went the furthest.

This one is failing here:

```
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-codec-standalone;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-extras-codec;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-net-mina;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-codec-core;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-extras-aci;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-extras-codec-api;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-ldap-model;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-asn1-ber;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-util;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-asn1-api;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.api#api-i18n;1.0.0.2.dse: not found
```

The key sections of build.sbt is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal // for testing
resolvers += "DataStax Repo" at "https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/"

val dseVersion = "6.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.dse" % "dse-spark-dependencies" % dseVersion % "provided" exclude(
    "org.slf4j", "log4j-over-slf4j", "org.apache.directory.api")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
).map(_.excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j","log4j-over-slf4j"),
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12"))
)  // Excluded to allow for Cassandra to run embedded
```

Seems to be a broken dependency. Can you please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following dependency

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.9"
```

Comment: Tried this and did not get the earlier dependency error. Got a different error now. :(

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /project/scala_apps/SparkBuildExamples/SparkBuildExamples-master/scala/sbt/dse/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[error] /project/scala_apps/SparkBuildExamples/SparkBuildExamples-master/scala/sbt/dse/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/example/WriteRead.scala:5:8: object SaveMode is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
[error]        ^

Comment: I picked up an earlier version of the package at https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/tree/6.0.0 which ties up to my dse version and it compiled without any issues. There were no differences in build.sbt file between these versions, but it just works. May be the libraries in the path have be updated to bundle these org.apache.directory.api packages. Sorry, not a scala expert.